# Regarding operations to add elements to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php array_push() vs myArray[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431629/php-array-push-vs-myarray)

Hello folks.

I know some ways to add an element to an array in PHP.

`$anArray[] =  $newElement;` <-I like this one

`array_push()` <-I've seen many people use it.

There are others, I'm sure.

**I'd like to know which of these is more efficient or if there's another way of doing it more efficiently.**

**NOTE:** I just want to add an element, could be at the end of the array. I mean that I won't specify what position the new element is to be added at.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've already looked at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assign operator will be slightly faster [there's no need to do a function call], but with `array_push()`, you can append more than one variable at once.

Answer (score 1):

None are more efficient than others.

PHP is a high-level language, and for the most part simple equivalent operations like these generate exactly the same opcodes.

In the rare case that there is a difference in the low-level code produced, it's at a level so fast that attempts to manipulate them would count as micro-optimisations.

In conclusion, simply don't worry about it. Write PHP code that does what it says it does and you'll be fine.

Comment: I know the difference might be slight. But if within a loop of, say, ten thousand iterations, these small differences might add up to something noticeable.

Comment: @Felipe: Granted, technically speaking that is possible. However, the compilation process will almost always render things like this completely null and void when the semantics are the same. _Trust_ your compiler, even [or especially] when it's PHP so the compilation process is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Are just adding a value to an array, regardless of the array key, or does the array key have to be specific? The first way you have suggested allows you to assign a custom key to the value, the `array_push()` will simply assign a numeric key one greater than the previous one.

Also, `array_push()` will allow you to add multiple values to an array at one time, like this:

```
array_push($myArray, "value1", "value2", "value3");
```

You can do the same with your first method, it would just be a lot of repetition. :)

If the key doesn't matter, or only need to add one value, then I would just say it is a matter of opinion.