# What is the meaning of []

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code as below and I am not sure what type of data variable `$ACTIVITYGROUPS[]` has and how do I read it ?

```
$ACTIVITYGROUPS[] = saprfc_table_read ($fce, "ACTIVITYGROUPS", $i);
```

When I did `print_r(saprfc_table_read ($fce, "ACTIVITYGROUPS", $i);` I got bunch of arrays without any seperator and not sure how to exactract the data. can someone tell me what does it do in above sentences ?

Here is what `print_r(saprfc_table_read ($fce, "ACTIVITYGROUPS", $i);` result gives me:

```
Array (
    [AGR_NAME] => Y:SECURITY_DISPLAY
    [FROM_DAT] => 20080813
    [TO_DAT] => 99991231
    [AGR_TEXT] => Security Display - Users & Roles
    [ORG_FLAG] => C
)

Array (
    [AGR_NAME] => Y:SECURITY_ADMIN_COMMON
    [FROM_DAT] => 20080813
    [TO_DAT] => 99991231
    [AGR_TEXT] => Security Administrator
    [ORG_FLAG] => C
)

Array (
    [AGR_NAME] => Y:LOCAL_TRANSPORT
    [FROM_DAT] => 20090810
    [TO_DAT] => 99991231
    [AGR_TEXT] => Transport into target client - DEV system only
    [ORG_FLAG] =>
)
```

Comment: _Please please please_ put a bit more time into your questions. Then you might actually get some help with this matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @Wrikken: Interestingly enough, there are *no square bracket symbols at all* on that page! I failed to find any using CTRL+F in Firefox. Looks like it's time to update it.

Comment: I just saw that, editing as we speak, I blatently assumed it was in there, it's about the default to point to when talking PHP operators. But indeed, not a duplicate of that one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431629/php-array-push-vs-myarray is one though.

Answer (score 30):

`[]` means **push** - put the given argument as a new element on the end of the array.  That means that `$ACTIVITYGROUPS` is an array*.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 1;       // Put 1 in position 0
$arr[] = "a";     // Put "a" in position 1
$arr[] = array()  // Put a new, empty array in position 2
```

As stated by the PHP docs, [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) has the same effect as `[]`.

---

***** If it's not an array, using `[]` will give you a syntax error:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in test.php on line 4

Comment: I'd like to point out that if `$test` is null, [it works](http://3v4l.org/7qhAD). However, pushing with `array_push()`, you [can't set the first parameter to null](http://3v4l.org/cj5DF).

Answer (score 4):

In many languages the `[]` notation stands for an array.
Is the same as php's [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php): it pushes an element in the variable that has `[]` at the end.

If the variable is null, you can consider the square brackets like a declaration of an array.

The same notation of push applies to Javascript, for example. When using it like `$var[] = 'a';` what happens is the same as [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) I was talking above. Just finds the next position in the array and adds there your value.

An array can be walked with `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do while` and you can check it's contents with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) functions.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I read it ?.

Since `saprfc_table_read` already returns an array, `$ACTIVITYGROUPS` will be an array of arrays (`[]` creates a new array element in array `$ACTIVITYGROUPS`). To read it, you can iterate over it with foreach:

```
$ACTIVITYGROUPS[] = saprfc_table_read ($fce,"ACTIVITYGROUPS",$i);

foreach ($ACTIVITYGROUPS as $group) {
    echo $group['AGR_NAME']; // echos Y:SECURITY_DISPLAY on first iteration
    echo $group['FROM_DAT']; // echos 20080813 on first iteration
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Also to display whole variable you can use `var_dump($ACTIVITYGROUPS)`

Answer (score 1):

It's an array, but the output you have shows that your nested arrays do not have keys. I'm sure they have the default keys of 0,1,2,3,4...and so on, but if you want to identify them by any meaningful way I'd suggest adjusting the keys of the data within the array.

```
print_r($ACTIVITYGROUPS); //this should output the whole array
print_r($ACTIVITYGROUPS[0]); //this should output just the first element of the array, which is also an array
//now you have an 'address' for the array that you understand, now lets output one of the values
foreach($ACTIVITYGROUPS as $key => $item){
    echo $item['ARG_NAME']; // this will output the ARG NAME from each of the arrays, in order
}
```

Comment: How do I return $ACTIVITYGROUPS[] with the same data in Function ? so I can read it after calling function....Thanks in Advance