# PHP - same code on one or multiple lines

Tags: php

This are two lines of codes. Could anyone tell me what the difference is between the first way and the second? I'd like both to do exactly the same thing.

```
   $test = isset($_POST['test'])?$_POST['test']:[];

if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    $test[] = $_POST['test'];
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: they are completely different.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one sets `$test` to an empty array if `$_POST['test']` is unset. However, the second one does not set `$test` to a default value. In fact, if `$_POST['test']` was unset, `$test` would be un-existent/undefined/etc.

You would need to run `$test = [];` at the beginning of the second one to archive the exact same result.

Comment: After the second one, `$test` isn't even null - it's undefined.

Comment: I'd also like to point at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933345/php-what-is-the-meaning-of#comment26432372_6933366).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveChen What does      $test = []; mean ??

Comment: `$test = []` means `$test = array()`, with PHP versions above 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

the top line would be equivalent to

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
     $test = $_POST['test'];
}else{
     $test = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first uses a ternary operator, which is a shorthand for `if (X) then $a = b else $a = c`, which sets `$test` to `$_POST['test']` if it isn't empty, or $test to an empty array.

The second example doesn't have the `else` case, so it will leave `$test` undefined if `$_POST['test']` is empty.

See also the ternary operator section of this page in the PHP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.